# Get all combinations of a vector of n-chars

Tags: rust

For a vector of n-chars, I'd like to get all possible combinations these chars can form.

```
let characters = vec!["a", "b"];
```

The expected 2² output would be: `["aa", "ab", "bb", "ba"]`

`combinations_with_replacement(2)` does not account for the inversed `["ba"]` case and `permutations(2)` does not include combinations of values of itself `["aa", "bb"]`.

Am I overlooking something in `itertools::Itertools` or is there simply no straight forward way to do this?

Comment: I believe this would be the [`.cartesian_product()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product) with itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple case like this you probably don't need any crates:

```rust
    let characters = vec!["a", "b"];
    let combinations : Vec<_> = characters.iter()
        .map(|&c| characters.iter().map(move |&d| d.to_owned() + c))
        .flatten()
        .collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=056b5afc5c75a0f205ac234fa617de21)

As pointed out in the comments, this solution is limited to a number of combinations known at compile time. If you need to a number of combinations which is only known at runtime, you could use this:

```rust
    let characters = vec!["a", "b"];

    let n=4; // The number of combinations
    
    let combinations : Vec<_> = (2..n).fold(
        characters.iter().map(|c| characters.iter().map(move |&d| d.to_owned() + *c)).flatten().collect(),
        |acc,_| acc.into_iter().map(|c| characters.iter().map(move |&d| d.to_owned() + &*c)).flatten().collect()
    );
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=61645a0850caf2cf9e1d429ccca86a0a)

If you did want to use itertools, as @kmdreko points out you would be using [`cartesian_product`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let characters = vec!["a", "b"];
    let combinations : Vec<_> = characters.iter()
        .cartesian_product(characters.iter())
        .map(|(&a, &b)| a.to_owned() + b)
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", combinations);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3fe010f47e23dbecc56754f91949baa8)

Note in the above solution that `cartesian_product` returns a tuple - so to obtain a string containing the combinations, we need to `map` the result.

Finally, if you want to use `cartesian_product` and you need a number of combinations known only at runtime:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let characters = vec!["a", "b"];
    let n = 4;
    
    let combinations : Vec<_> = (2..n).fold(
        characters.iter().cartesian_product(characters.iter()).map(|(&a, &b)| a.to_owned() + b).collect(),
        |acc, _| acc.into_iter().cartesian_product(characters.iter()).map(|(a, b)| a.to_owned() + b).collect()
    );
    println!("{:?}", combinations);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8cc209e8cd897520997e857207eaf15e)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, these work when the number of chars in the vector is n = 2, but not for any arbitrary number n (n² instead of n^n).

Comment: Just call `cartesian_product` n-1 times

Comment: @Enum The number of chars in the vector can be anything, but the number of permutations is fixed. I think you mean you want a solution for m^n. I have updated the answer to cater for a dynamic number of combinations.