# Is there a way to get all possible combinations of fixed size in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get all possible windows, or chunks or partials of a specific size from a `Vec` of integers.

The `windows` and `chunks` methods only return portions of contiguous elements.

For example, if I have this Vec: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, I want to get:

```
[
 [1,2,3,4],
 [2,3,4,5],
 [3,4,5,6],
 [1,3,4,5],
 [1,4,5,6],
 [2,4,5,6],
 [1,2,4,5],
 [1,2,5,6],
...
]
```

So: all possible combinations of size n of the initial elements.
How can I accomplish something like that?

Comment: _"chunks methods only returns the continuos ones"_ It's hard to understand what you mean, but when using the [`chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) method for slices, the slices obtained do not overlap. Please [edit] to clarify what you mean, possibly with an example.

Comment: edit: added example an clarification

Comment: The word for this is [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). There's an [implementation](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.combinations) of it in the `itertools` crate.

Comment: Very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746583/get-all-combinations-of-a-vector-of-n-chars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called [`combinations`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.combinations):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;
fn main() {
    let combinations: Vec<_> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].into_iter().combinations(4).collect();
    println!("{combinations:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e9a29057ba9f1d2b2b1d8a71cf7876fb)